# get last inserted id in sql server 2008

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008

I want to get last inserted id of particular table. can any one tell me how i can get that?
we have `mysql_insert_id()` in mysql. Do we have similar kind of function in sql server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this function to make it easy :)... if you have more then one db resource just pass that into the mssql_query request.  This will retrieve the last unique id generated on that resource connection.

```
mssql_query("insert into data(name) values('bob')");
$id = getLastId();

function getLastId() {
    $result = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("select @@IDENTITY as id"));
    return $result['id'];
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into SCOPE_IDENTITY too, since both @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY work in a slightly different way.

Comment: In your solution i require to run an extra query.Can't we do this without running an extra query in system?

Comment: nope. its only on inserts so will not be an issue.  also since it uses the same database link it really wont make a difference.  You could write a stored procedure that can return whatever you want back but this is easier if you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

something like this works very nicely

```
$sql = "insert into tables(field) values (value);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
$db = getConnection();
$results = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query($sql));
$lastid=$results['computed'];
```