# Last Inserted id in MSSQL PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Need a help. I want to get last inserted id from database in insert query from MSSQL database using PHP as a Programming language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494502/get-last-inserted-id-in-sql-server-2008 refer this and also this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574851/how-to-get-insert-id-in-mssql-in-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have mysql_insert_id, mysqli_insert_id and $mysqli->insert_id for mysql, mysqli procedural and mysqli object style.
All depends on mysql extension you are using

Comment: The question was about Microsoft SQL (MSSQL) not MySQL ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using PDO, there is a method called lastInsertId for that. If you change your database, your PHP code will be the same, the only change will be the PDO driver.

Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php