# How can I get the last record inserted ID using php (ODBC)?

Tags: php, sql-server

I think I am over complicating things here, I am trying to pass the ID of the inserted record.

I have managed to get this working on MYSQL using the following code:

```
$queryadd = "INSERT INTO events (event_date,event_orig_name,event_orig_tel,event_orig_email,event_title,event_time_lunch,event_room,event_cater,event_type,event_attendees,event_diary,event_user_email,event_user_tel,event_status,event_user_id) VALUES ('$event_date','$event_orig_name','$event_orig_tel','$event_orig_email','$event_title','$event_time_lunch','$event_room','$event_cater','$event_type','$event_attendees','$event_dieray','$event_user_email','$event_user_tel','$event_status','$event_user_id')";

$resultadd = $conn->query($queryadd);
$ideventadd = $conn->insert_id;
if(!$resultadd) die($conn->error);
```

So, what is the alternative to get this working on a ODBC server, my code is as follows:

```
$queryadd = "INSERT INTO events (event_date,event_orig_name,event_orig_tel,event_orig_email,event_title,event_time_lunch,event_room,event_cater,event_type,event_attendees,event_diary,event_user_email,event_user_tel,event_status,event_user_id) VALUES ('$event_date','$event_orig_name','$event_orig_tel','$event_orig_email','$event_title','$event_time_lunch','$event_room','$event_cater','$event_type','$event_attendees','$event_dieray','$event_user_email','$event_user_tel','$event_status','$event_user_id')";

$resultadd = odbc_exec($connect, $queryadd);
if(!$resultadd) die($connect->error);

$queryaddid = "SELECT @@identity AS evtid";
$resultaddid = odbc_exec($connect, $queryaddid);
$rowaddid = odbc_fetch_array($resultaddid);
$ideventadd = $rowaddid['event_id'];
if(!$resultaddid) die($connect->error);
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494502/get-last-inserted-id-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Drew It looks like OP's asking how to get this working in MS SQL Server, so that wouldn't be a dupe.

Comment: thx @EdCottrell, retracted

Comment: Duplicate question, answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432893/sql-server-last-inserted-id#answer-16432942

Comment: Thanks all. Yeah this a duplicate question and my answer is found. But when I use the following query code ($ideventadd = odbc_exec($connect, "SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM events;");) the email works but the id says Resource ID of #5?

Comment: @Craig - that's really a different question. `odbc_exec` will be returning a recordset (your Resource); you need to get the first record from it to get your actual ID

Comment: @andrewsi - I have updated my question as it is actually ODBC i am trying  to get the last inserted record ID.